# What is the 'Layer' box in 'Save Vector Layer' good for?

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, in the 'save vector layer as' window, under OGR creation options, what is the 'Layer' box for?

Answer (score 4):

That is for adding OGR layer creation options.  So OGR providers allow you to supply additional layer options when creating a new file.

See http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_pg.html for an example

> - GEOM_TYPE: The GEOM_TYPE layer creation option can be set to one of
>     "geometry", "geography" (PostGIS >= 1.5), "BYTEA" or "OID" to force
>     the type of geometry used for a table. For a PostGIS database,
>     "geometry" is the default value.
> - OVERWRITE: This may be "YES" to
>     force an existing layer of the desired name to be destroyed before
>     creating the requested layer.
> - LAUNDER: This may be "YES" to force new
>     fields created on this layer to have their field names "laundered"
>     into a form more compatible with PostgreSQL. This converts to lower
>     case and converts some special characters like "-" and "#" to "_". If
>     "NO" exact names are preserved. The default value is "YES". If
>     enabled the table (layer) name will also be laundered.
>     ...

Comment: Um, thanks.  Can any of it be used to label or symbolize data when exporting to kml??

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: The layer box becomes essential if you want to export to GPX. The driver needs some hints how to squeeze the data and attribute columns into the GPX data scheme.

Comment: Ah, that would be useful. Thanks.  Are there any hints for the user on how to give the driver hints?